# Aliasing ID parameter in URL as string in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

What i'm trying to do is to rewrite URLs to make them more SEO friendly but i still want to pass a parameter as an int ID.

For example, a URL pointing to a  news article might look like this:
"www.domain.com/category-id/article-id" or "domain.com/5/3"

What i want to do is to rewrite the URL everywhere so that the title of the category and the title of the article are written into the URL so it becomes f.x. "domain.com/politics/some-title" but i still want to pass the ID of the article as an argument to the controller action. This is less important for the category but it's something i want to do with the article-id since it's unique but the title might not be.

I have checked out Attribute Routing and looked through some Routing guides and questions but haven't found anything that lets me implement this functionality. I've just started using ASP.NET MVC so i haven't been able to look into anything too advanced.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to make the article title unique and from the controller action you have to get the article based on the title.

I see you are trying to group the articles based on category. When I initially created my [blog](http://www.prideparrot.com) I thought the same-thing but soon realized it's not a flexible approach because of couple of reasons.

1. Say you wrote one article with name `some-title` and dropped it under a category say `politics` and so the url will be `domain.com/politics/some-title` but at a later point of time you thought to move the article to another category say 'international-politics' therefore your url now has to be changed to `domain.com/international-politics/some-title` and you break the old url and whoever has bookmarked that link will now receive 404. A better way would be organize the urls based on the posted date and that's not going to change something like `http://domain.com/archive/yyyy/mm/dd/unique_title`
2. Sometimes you want to label an article with more than one category and at that time a tag based approach will become a better choice compared to category based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solutions:

1) domain.com/categoryName/articleID/articleName/
2) domain.com/date/categoryName/articleName (date should help make articleName unique)
3) domain.com/categoryName/articleName?id=xxx

Nothing fancy, but those approaches will work.

Comment: Well it's not the solution i was hoping for but it would work :)

Still, thank you for taking the time to answer.